# Multiple classes animating on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I'm styling a menu that has a toggleClass in there, so far no problem, but when i have the hover function and i do hover then mouse on the menu elements the function executes on all the menu's elements, how do i manage to only affect one at the time?

The menu:

```
<div id="menu_segundo">
    <ul>

        <li class="curso av">AV</li>
        <li class="curso dc">DC</li>
        <li class="curso dp">DP</li>
        <li class="curso pa">PA</li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

The Css

```
#menu_segundo {
margin-top: 20px;
float: right;
background: #58ACFA;
}

.curso {
color: white;
font-family: DIN;
width: 25px;
height: 10px;
border-left: 2px solid white;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 0px;
}



.expand_menu{
color: white;
font-family: DIN;
width: 150px;
height: 10px;
border-left: 2px solid white;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 0px;
}
```

The JS

```
 var segundo = $('#menu_segundo').find('ul').children();

segundo.hover(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('expand_menu');
})
```

Here is a [DEMO](http://liveweave.com/A6mXFt) of the menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not need JS to function.

Simply change `.expand_menu` to `.curso:hover` in your CSS.

Alternatively, to fix your JS use:

```
$("#menu_segundo").on("hover", ".curso", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expand_menu');
});
```

The problem with your JS is that you are toggling the class on all `li` elements. `segundo` is set to equal **all** `li` elements, not the one being hovered.

**UPDATE**

There is a problem beyond the initial applying of classes, the CSS/HTML structure is not rendering correctly. The problem is that extending one of the `li` elements increases the size of the entire `ul` moving all `li` elements in the process.

Updating the HTML to this:

```
<div id="menu_segundo">
    <div class="curso av">AV</div>
    <div class="curso dc">DC</div>
    <div class="curso dp">DP</div>
    <div class="curso pa">PA</div>
</div>
```

And updating the CSS to:

```
#menu_segundo {
    margin-top: 20px;
    float: right;
}

.curso {
    color: white;
    font-family: DIN;
    width: 25px;
    border-left: 2px solid white;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    background: #58ACFA;
    float: right;
    clear:both;
}

.curso:hover{
    width: 150px;
}
```

Gets the desired behavior. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BW4S3/) for an example.

**Note**

The CSS can also be set to

```
.expand_menu{
    width: 150px;
}
```

To continue with the JS solution.

Comment: i tried the css you said, same problem, and the jquery doesnt work

Comment: @Miguel I think the problem has to do with your CSS not doing what you expect, not that the solution I provided isn't working. When you hover over an `li` it does apply the class as you requested. What is the problem you are experiencing now? How is it supposed to look?

Comment: i wanted that when i hover on one element it runs the effect, only on that one element and not on all of them, here is a demo where it shows the problem: http://liveweave.com/A6mXFt

Comment: @Miguel Yes. The problem is with your CSS. It is behaving exactly as you have told it. The problem is, the settings you are giving it does not do what you think/want it to. I'm working on a fix to update my answer with.

Comment: @Miguel The problem is that when you make one of the `li` elements bigger, it makes the entire `ul` bigger, so the smaller `li` elements move with it. I'm having trouble fixing the CSS using the `ul`/`li` structure, does it need to be that way?

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
var segundo = $('#menu_segundo li')

segundo.hover(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('expand_menu');
})
```